# Blender only renders video up to one second

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render an animation 1,500 frames long at 60 fps. Every time I render it, I open the video file and it would only be one second long. I tried rendering it multiple times and with multiple formats. I even tried rendering the frames as images and rendering them into a video with the video editor and still the output video was only one second long. I know that every frame of the 1,500 was rendered and in the timeline. Frame start and end are also set accurately. The file name also says FILENAME-1500 so I know the frames should be there but they're not. Is there any fix to this?

Comment: Can we see your render/output settings screenshot?

Comment: Did you set the frame range to be rendered (frame start and frame end) in the Dimensions settings?

Comment: Yes I did. I kept trying to figure it out and I know I entered the start and end frame properly. When I rendered it in parts it worked alright. I think it might have to do with AVI Raw vs. AVI JPEG but I'm not sure.

Comment: I doubt it. Raw and JPEG's are just different image formats that each frame is rendered to, so I don't think that's the problem but I could be wrong. :)